# Creating new excel files from data of each spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I just need advice on how to approach a problem. I need to create a new file for each spreadsheet of an excel file (it has about 80 sheets), that contains the corresponding spreadsheets data.

Is it possible to use xlrd library to do something like this?

Comment: Assuming it's a one-time thing, I'd do something like this: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/785-excel-save-export-sheet-as-new-workbook.html#vba  However, if it's a repeatable/programmatic process that requires python, then... that probably won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is one solution

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\xy\\Desktop\\Report.xls', 'Sheet 1',decimal=',')

df2 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\xy\\Desktop\\Report.xls', 'Sheet 2',decimal=',')

df3 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\xy\\Desktop\\Report.xls', 'Sheet 3',decimal=',')

df4 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\xy\\Desktop\\Report.xls', 'Sheet 4',decimal=',')

df5 = pd.merge(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

Comment: I had something similar to the for loop. I am just focusing on looking at one excel file and creating a file for each spreadsheet within that one excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using `Pandas` library:

```
#Import pandas module (if you don't have it open the command line and run: pip install pandas)
import pandas as pd

#Read the Excel file to a Pandas DataFrame
#Note: change "file_name" to the name of your Excel file
#This will give you a dictionary containing one DataFrame per each sheet on the Excel file 
data = pd.read_excel("file_name.xlsx", sheet_name=None)

#Iterate through the dictionary
count = 0
for d in data:
    #Give different names according to the sheet where data came from
    count = count + 1
    name = "sheet_" + str(count)
    #Save to an Excel file
    d.to_excel(name + ".xlsx")
```